# C# String interpolation. Use string when decimal? is null

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I have the following C$ String interpolation:

```
decimal? approved = null;

var text = $"new {{ Approved = { approved ?? ""null"" } }}"
```

In this case, since approved is null, text value should be:

```
new { Approved = null }
```

But I get a compilation error:

```
Operator '??" cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal?' and 'string'
```

If I use the following:

```
var text = "new {{ Approved = { approved } }}"
```

The text value will become the following which I do not want:

```
new { Approved = }
```

Comment: You are trying to set a string value to either a decimal or a string. That's why you are getting the error.

Comment: approved?.ToString() should solve this...

Comment: `var text = $"new {{ Approved = { (approved?.ToString() ?? "null") } }}";`

Answer (score 6):

```
decimal? approved = null;
var text = $"new {{ Approved = { (approved?.ToString() ?? "null") } }}";
```

Both sides of the null coalescing operator `??` need to be of the same type, so call `ToString` and add the null conditional operator `?` to ensure that does not throw an NRE.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted doesn't compile. You can't do this: var approved = null. To get what you want, you would need to do this:

```
    decimal? approved = null;
    var text = new { Approved = approved == null ? "null" : approved.ToString() }
```